# How to get full data from mongoose when schema has reference

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

This is the schema. My frontend needs [content, name, email] at the same time. How to get those three data and render to frontend at the same time? Can you provide a sample JS code to do that?

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref:'User'
    },
    content:{
        type: String
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, you can use populate to get data from reference:

```
post.find()
        .where("field")
        .in([criteria])
        
        .populate("author")
        .exec(function (e, posts) {
            if (e) {
                //do error handling here
            }
            if (posts) {
               return posts;
            }
        });
```

or
create post model
create author model

```
 post.find()
        .where("field")
        .in([criteria])
        
        .populate({
            path: 'author',
            model: authorModel
            )}
        .exec(function (e, posts) {
            if (e) {
                //do error handling here
            }
            if (posts) {
               return posts;
            }
        });
```